What is the point of multiple samples?
In Metal Shading Language, there is an imageblock which is dependent on width, height and number of samples. How will the number of samples change said data structure? Moving further, there is an array of samplers and even structures of samplers. Why would I want to sample the same texture multiple times? In my view, the result will always be the same.
According to the documentation PDF, "sample" implies the ability to read from a texture with and without a sampler.
